# How can I visualize ground truth bounding boxes in Darknet?

Tags: python, deep-learning, yolo, darknet

I come to Darknet from Turi create which is a Yolo implementation. There was an easy way to visualize the ground truth bounding boxes. I did some changes to the coordinates and I would like to check on one image if the transformations are correct. Is there any easy way to to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [opencv function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9):

```py
cv2.rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness, lineType, shift)
```

For example, in case of a bounding box:

```py
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 00), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize darknet annotation format with this: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/Yolo_mark

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool out https://github.com/waittim/draw-YOLO-box.git

It helps visualizing the boxes in all your files.

A Drawback is it creates a new image file with bboxes for each image. This could take up a lot of space.